# Loading wrong dimens value according to screen orientation

Tags: android

I can't load the right value of dimens.xml according to my screen orientation.
My activity needs to be forced to landscape on tablets and portrait for smartphones.
Here you are some code.

values\dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="drawer_content_padding">0dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

values-sw600dp-land\dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="drawer_content_padding">340dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
        if (config.smallestScreenWidthDp >= 600){
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.orientationtest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@dimen/drawer_content_padding"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

So, running my App on tablet if the home screen is in portrait mode this is what I got.
[image]

Running my App on tablet if the home screen is in landscape mode this is what I got.
[image]

**Problem: I need to get the value 340.0 in both cases**

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you correctly, but if you are in landscape mode on your tablet (that has >600) it will take the value from values-sw600dp-land\dimens.xml file and it can't be 0

Comment: @MishaAkopov my activity is aways in landscape mode, but my tablet outside my app can be portrait or landscape. When both are landscape thats fine, but when outside my app is portrait my app doesn't load the dimens of values-sw600dp-land folder

Comment: So you want both values to be 340dp always

Comment: Yes, always 340dp, I had edit my question sorry for the misstyping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use that dimension for both orientations you should place that `dimens.xml` file to the folder `values-sw600dp`, not to the `values-sw600dp-land`

Answer (score 1):

I've examined your code on my device. Everything works correctly. The only problem is that your activity doesn't recreate itself after orientation change. I think, the only thing that can it is

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
```

In your manifest, in  for your Activity . Please check.

If removing this option(configChanges) in manifest causes sideeffects in your app, you should handle this yourself in

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.e(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged: " + getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.drawer_content_padding));
    }
```

After you change your table from portrait to landscape, `onConfigurationChanged` is called and inside this method there will be correct dimen values (***340dp***) and you can set it manually to your views.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, if my activity recreate itself removing the configChanges you metioned it works. Unfortunately I can't do this because a lot of side effects in my original App. Is there some other way to do this without recreating it?

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. It works but I think your solution is a bit complicated, that's why I will accept @DmitryArc answer because adding `-land`file isn't a problem in my case

Comment: Ok, my solution is more general :) Glad to hear your problem is solved